# SQL for joining 2 tables but a bit complicated for my understanding

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Got a situation thats a bit beyond my understanding.

Table A has the Product, Country and Factory
Table B has the Product, Factory and city.

The scenario is such that sales forecast data flows from the country level via the factory and then to city level. We have factories only in Rotterdam and Amsterdam. The issue is such that the factories in Table A need to be the same as the factory in table B.

I have to clean data for situations C&D where the factories in Table A are wrong and need cleaning. I therefore first need to identify these wrong records:

Here is what I got so far by joining Table A and B

**select A.Prod,A.country,A.factory,B.Prod,B.factory,B.City from Table1 A, Table2 B where and A.Prod=B.Prod and A.Factory <>B.Factory**

Of course I can find a specific known wrong record by using below SQL, but I need to find for all wrong records without specifying any product or

**select A.Prod,A.country,A.factory,B.Prod,B.factory,B.City from Table1 A, Table2 B where A.Prod=B.Prod and A.Factory <>B.Factory 
and A.Country ='Norway' and A.Factory ='Rotterdam' and B.City ='Oslo'**

## Situation 1

### Table A

Product Country     Factory
ProdA   Switzerland Rotterdam

### Table B

Product Factory City
ProdA   Rotterdam   Geneva

## Situation 2

### Table A

Product Country     Factory
Prod    Germany Rotterdam

### Table B

Product Factory City
ProdB   Rotterdam   Dresden

## Situation 3

### Table A

Product Country     Factory
ProdC   Norway  Rotterdam

### Table B

Product Factory City
ProdC   Amsterdam   Oslo

## Situation 4

### Table A

Product Country     Factory
ProdD   Finland Rotterdam

### Table B

Product Factory City
ProdD   Amsterdam   Helsinki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand Your projection for the country in Table A, has to be for a city in table B, which exists in the country in table A.

So, in situation 1, we have 
Table A country = Switzerland, Table B city = Geneva. 
Since, Geneva is in Switzerland, this is fine 
In situation 2, we have 
Table A country = Germany, Table B city = Dresden
Since Dresden is in Germany this is fine.

This gives us a clue on how we can attack the problem.

Step 1. Setup a table for your expected country/city

```
CREATE TABLE COUNTRY_CITY (COUNTRY VARCHAR(60), CITY VARCHAR(60));
```

STEP 2. Insert the values for expected country/city into table

```
INSERT INTO COUNTRY_CITY(COUNTRY,CITY) VALUES('GERMANY','DRESDEN');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY_CITY(COUNTRY,CITY) VALUES('SWITZERLAND','GENEVA');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY_CITY(COUNTRY,CITY) VALUES('NORWAY','OSLO');
INSERT INTO COUNTRY_CITY(COUNTRY,CITY) VALUES('FINLAND','HELSINKI');
```

STEP 3.

```
select A.Prod,A.country, A.factory, B.Prod, B.factory, B.City,
       COUNTRY_CITY.CITY
from 
Table1 A
INNER JOIN Table2 B ON A.Prod=B.Prod 
INNER JOIN COUNTRY_CITY ON A.COUNTRY = COUNTRY_CITY.COUNTRY
where  COUNTRY_CITY.CITY = B.city and A.Factory <> B.Factory
```

So in step 3, we give the database the knowledge of which city belongs to which country, so that we can do a join from Table A to table B. Once you get that, then the condition on the not matching factories should be the records that you are looking for

Comment: Thanks Neil. This helps exactly as needed.

Comment: @redoctober Can you please upvote the answer, to mark it as the right answer? Thanks.